# How to get the max count of groups using Pandas groupby, using alphabetical order to break any ties

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Susan', 'Cindy', 'Paul', 'Paul', 'Jon', 'Larry', 'Cindy', 'Larry', 'Larry', 'David', 'David', 'David', 'Eric', 'Cindy', 'Paul'],
    'city': ['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'London', 'London', 'London', 'London', 'Sydney', 'Sydney', 'Sydney', 'Sydney', 'Sydney', 'Sydney', 'Sydney', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo']
})
```

For each city, I'd like to return the person with the max count within that city.  In cases of a tie, I'd like to use the alphabetical order (closest to 'A') of the person.

The desired dataframe would look as follows:

```
city         person
New York     Bob
London       Paul
Sydney       David
Tokyo        Cindy
```

I believe I can do this using `groupby()` and `idxmax()`, but I'm not sure how.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.sort_values('person')\                 #Sort to get alphabetical order
  .groupby('city', sort=False)['person']\ #Groupby city sort False to keep city in order
  .apply(pd.Series.mode)\                 #Apply mode to get most frequent occurrence
  .xs(0, level=1)                         #Use xs to get values for first level of city
```

Output:

```
city
New York      Bob
London       Paul
Tokyo       Cindy
Sydney      David
Name: person, dtype: object
```

And, you can add `.reset_index()` to get a dataframe back.

```
       city person
0  New York    Bob
1    London   Paul
2     Tokyo  Cindy
3    Sydney  David
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you( using `groupby` and `first`):

```
grouped_df = df.reset_index().groupby(['city', 'person']).count()
grouped_df = grouped_df.reset_index().sort_values(['index', 'person'], ascending=[False, True])
grouped_df = grouped_df.rename(columns={'index': 'count'})
grouped_df.groupby(['city']).first()
```

Output (you can drop the `count` column if not needed):

```
| city     | person   |   count |
|:---------|:---------|--------:|
| London   | Paul     |       2 |
| New York | Bob      |       3 |
| Sydney   | David    |       3 |
| Tokyo    | Cindy    |       1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

**Intermediate**

value_count & grouped by index

```
df.value_counts(['city', 'person']).groupby(level=0).head(1)
```

```
city      person
New York  Bob       3
Sydney    David     3
London    Paul      2
Tokyo     Cindy     1
```

If you want to sort the data by the order of appearance of city, you can use `reindex` additionally.

```
df.value_counts(['city', 'person']).groupby(level=0).head(1).reindex(df['city'].unique(), level=0)
```

```
city      person
New York  Bob       3
London    Paul      2
Sydney    David     3
Tokyo     Cindy     1
```

**Full Code**

```
(df.value_counts(['city', 'person'])
   .groupby(level=0).head(1)
   .reindex(df['city'].unique(), level=0)
   .index.to_frame(index=False))
```

output:

```
    city        person
0   New York    Bob
1   London      Paul
2   Sydney      David
3   Tokyo       Cindy
```